# Converting this FreeT (explicitly recursive data type) function to work on FT (church encoding)

Tags: haskell, free-monad, church-encoding

I'm using the [FreeT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#t:FreeT) type from the *free* library to write this function which "runs" an underlying `StateT`:

```
runStateFree
    :: (Functor f, Monad m)
    => s
    -> FreeT f (StateT s m) a
    -> FreeT f m (a, s)
runStateFree s0 (FreeT x) = FreeT $ do
    flip fmap (runStateT x s0) $ \(r, s1) -> case r of
      Pure y -> Pure (y, s1)
      Free z -> Free (runStateFree s1 <$> z)
```

However, I'm trying to convert it to work on [FT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free-Church.html), the church-encoded version, instead:

```
runStateF
    :: (Functor f, Monad m)
    => s
    -> FT f (StateT s m) a
    -> FT f m (a, s)
runStateF s0 (FT x) = FT $ \ka kf -> ...
```

but I'm not quite having the same luck.  Every sort of combination of things I get seems to not quite work out.  The closest I've gotten is

```
runStateF s0 (FT x) = FT $ \ka kf ->
    ka =<< runStateT (x pure (\n -> _ . kf (_ . n)) s0
```

But the type of the first hole is `m r -> StateT s m r` and the type the second hole is `StateT s m r -> m r`...which means we necessarily lose the state in the process.

I know that all `FreeT` functions are possible to write with `FT`.  Is there a nice way to write this that doesn't involve round-tripping through `FreeT` (that is, in a way that requires explicitly matching on `Pure` and `Free`)?  (I've tried manually inlining things but I don't know how to deal with the recursion using different `s`s in the definition of `runStateFree`).  Or maybe this is one of those cases where the explicit recursive data type is necessarily more performant than the church (mu) encoding?

Comment: Perhaps you could "warm up" by manually writing the isomorphism between `FreeT` and `FT` from scratch, which might show you the technique you need in a context with fewer degrees of freedom

Comment: @luqui Based on my previous experiments with this `FT` isn't exactly isomorphic to `FreeT`, it's "larger" in a certain sense

Comment: @luqui i suppose that was what I was going for when I was trying to 'inline' the isomorphism functions...but I couldn't find a way to get around the "recursing with a different `s0`" part.  But maybe trying to write the isomorphism myself, instead of looking at the pre-written ones, might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the definition. There are no tricks in the implementation itself. Don't think and make it type check. Yes, at least one of these `fmap` is morally questionable, but the difficulty is actually to convince ourselves it does the Right thing.

```
runStateF
    :: (Functor f, Monad m)
    => s
    -> FT f (StateT s m) a
    -> FT f m (a, s)
runStateF s0 (FT run) = FT $ \return0 handle0 ->
  let returnS a = StateT (\s -> fmap (\r -> (r, s)) (return0 (a, s)))
      handleS k e = StateT (\s -> fmap (\r -> (r, s)) (handle0 (\x -> evalStateT (k x) s) e))
  in evalStateT (run returnS handleS) s0
```

We have two stateless functions (i.e., plain `m`)

```
return0 :: a -> m r
handle0 :: forall x. (x -> m r) -> f x -> m r
```

and we must wrap them in two stateful (`StateT s m`) variants with the signatures below. The comments that follow give some details about what is going on in the definition of `handleS`.

```
returnS :: a -> StateT s m r
handleS :: forall x. (x -> StateT s m r) -> f x -> StateT s m r

-- 1.                                               --    ^   grab the current state 's' here
-- 2.                                               --      ^ call handle0 to produce that 'm'
-- 3.                             ^ here we will have to provide some state 's': pass the current state we just grabbed.
--                                  The idea is that 'handle0' is stateless in handling 'f x',
--                                  so it is fine for this continuation (x -> StateT s m r) to get the state from before the call to 'handle0'
```

There is an apparently dubious use of `fmap` in `handleS`, but it is valid as long as `run` *never looks* at the states produced by `handleS`. It is almost immediately thrown away by one of the `evalStateT`.

In theory, there exist terms of type `FT f (StateT s m) a` which break that invariant. In practice, that almost certainly doesn't occur; you would really have to go out of your way to do something morally wrong with those continuations.

In the following complete gist, I also show how to test with QuickCheck that it is indeed equivalent to your initial version using `FreeT`, with concrete evidence that the above invariant holds:

https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/a0afa3ca2ea9e39b400cde25b5012d18

Comment: Thank you!  It's interesting that the equivalence is not immediately obvious, and that it is prudent to run some tests to make sure.  The fact that `FT` is "bigger" than `Free` definitely makes things strange.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that no, as even something as simple as `cutoff` converts to `FreeT`:

```hs
cutoff :: (Functor f, Monad m) => Integer -> FT f m a -> FT f m (Maybe a)
cutoff n = toFT . FreeT.cutoff n . fromFT
```

---

In general, you're probably looking at:

```hs
improve :: Functor f => (forall m. MonadFree f m => m a) -> Free f a
```

> Improve the asymptotic performance of code that builds a free monad with only binds and returns by using F behind the scenes.

I.e. you'll construct `Free` efficiently, but then do whatever you need to do with `Free` (maybe again, by `improve`ing).

Comment: This is essentially an appeal to authority.  It would be nice to see *why* converting to `FreeT` is good or bad.